# Connecting rectangles with lines in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm looking to build the following (ignore the bottom green line) mock up in D3:

[image]

with this data:

```
var treeData = [{
  "name": "Channel",
  "parent": "null",
  "groups": [{
    "name": "Phone",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Issue",
      "parent": "Phone",
      "groups": [{
          "name": "Tech",
        },{
          "name": "Non-tech",
        }]
    }]
  },{
    "name": "Chat"
  }]
}]
```

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Would trees (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) help?

Comment: That's almost exactly what I'm looking for but I had to modify the data to work with the tree (I'm using a simpler tree). Basically I had to change "groups" to "children" and the structure ends up different from what I'm looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/0d8tym7h/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using [JsPlumb Community Edition](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/home.html). I merely built off [this tutorial](http://www.freedevelopertutorials.com/jsplumb-tutorial/).